# Why a structure containing a struct pointer member compile but containing a simple struct member does not compile

Tags: c, struct, types, structure, definition

While learning about structures in c language I am confused that why the following code does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
struct data{
    int a;
    int b;
    struct data c;
};

typedef struct data data_t;

int main()
{
    data_t mydata = {1,2,{3,4}};
    std::cout << mydata.a;

    return 0;
}
```

But this code compiles without any error.

```
#include <iostream>
struct data{
    int a;
    int b;
    struct data *c;
};

typedef struct data data_t;

int main()
{
    data_t mydata = {1,2,&mydata};
    std::cout << (*mydata.c).a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: what is the size of the struct in the first code?

Comment: You cannot learn C using a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A structure is a complete type after the closing brace.

From the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 8 The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a
> struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation
> unit. The struct-declaration-list is a sequence of declarations for
> the members of the structure or union. If the struct-declaration-list
> contains no named members, no anonymous structures, and no anonymous
> unions, the behavior is undefined. **The type is incomplete until
> immediately after the } that terminates the list, and complete
> thereafter.**

Or from the C++ 14 Standard (9.2 Class members)

> 2 **A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or
> complete type) at the closing } of the class specifier**. Within the
> class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within
> function bodies, default arguments, using-declarations introducing
> inheriting constructors (12.9), exception-specifications, and
> brace-or-equal-initializer s for non-static data members (including
> such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete
> within its own class member-specification.

So in this declaration

```
struct data{
    int a;
    int b;
    struct data c;
};
```

where the data member `c` is declared the structure is not yet a complete type. So the compiler does not know what is the size of the data member `c`. So the compiler is unable to generate the definition of the structure.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 1. ... At various points within a translation unit an object type may be
>    incomplete (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of
>    objects of that type) or complete (having sufficient information).

On the other hand, pointers are always complete types. Their sizes are always known.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> — A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object
> type, called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object
> whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type.
> A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called
> ‘‘pointer to T’’. The construction of a pointer type from a referenced
> type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’. **A pointer type is a
> complete object type**.

Pay attention to that your programs are not C programs because C does not have the header `<iostream>`. You showed C++ programs.

Nevertheless the quotes I provided are valid also for C++.

Comment: This means if the pointer member was added at point "b", it would point to member "a", and not to member"c" if c is a simple member. Is this right?

Comment: @WAQAS  I have not understood what you wrote. A pointer is a complete type. It size is known to the compiler. So the compiler knows what will be the size of a structure with such a data  member. Relative to your example the compiler knows the size of the data member struct data *c; The size of a pointer either 4 or 8 bytes depending on the used system.

Comment: @WAQAS The data member struct data *c; points nowhere because it is not a definition of an object. It is a definition of a structure type. Creating an object of this type you can assign to the data member any valid value.

Comment: Thanks for your explaining, I now understand that pointer member in a struct may point to any object of any type even to struct in which it is contained.